# Getting unknown function 'service::is-installed' when using nant

Tags: windows, build, nant

Using NANT 0.92, the statement is as follows:

```
<servicecontroller action="Stop" service="${mon.service}" if="${service::is-installed(mon.service,'.') and service::is-running(mon.service,'.')}" timeout="300000" />
```

results in

```
17:46:20 Unknown function 'service::is-installed'.
17:46:20 Expression: ${service::is-installed(Monitoring.service,'.') and service::is-running(Monitoring.service,'.')}
17:46:20               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Had to revert back to

Any idea?
According to [Documentation](http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/service.is-installed.html) this should work.

Also [this](http://www.prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/2/using_nant_on_creating_windows_services) is using the same technique.

Comment: What version of NAnt contrib are you using?

Comment: Was not using any, just nant 0.92 - are those like msbuild community tasks?

Comment: The link you gave (http://nantcontrib.sourceforge.net/release/0.85/help/functions/service.is-installed.html) says the feature is in NAnt contrib. Look at the last line of the web page.

Comment: This is correct indeed - thanks @mjwills